# nextLevel Method

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

How do I make a method that switches levels for me? I'm using cocos2d btw. I'm not talking about the simple replaceScene, I want a method that, when called, will change from say level 10 to level 11. I'm not sure how to achieve this, but my levels are simply named LevelOne, LevelTwo, LevelThree, etc. I thought about doing

```
-(void)nextLevel:(ccTime)dt {
    if (currentLevel += 1) { //CURRENT LEVEL + ONE LEVEL 

    }
}
```

but of course, just adding one to currentLevel (an int I have that has the current level the user is at) would just make the number +1.
I don't want a method that detects the level, I want a method that takes currentLevel and goes to the nextLevel.

Comment: try putting them in an array and just going to the next index?

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Ok so I made an NSMutableArray called levelArray. I'm not exactly sure how to use levelArray. After initilizing it, will this work?

for (currentLevel in levelArray) {

But then of course, I'd have to add currentLevel to levelArray, which I'm also not sure how to do :(

Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: I'm not sure how to navigate through the array, and how to add all the Levels and also currentLevel into the levelArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One nice way would be to store your data in a linked list. [Here's a nice article](http://www.jonathansaggau.com/blog/2007/02/core_data_double_linked_list_h.html) on how to implement one in Core Data. I'm actually using this in my app currently; while the setup is a little complex, the extreme benefit comes with lines of code like this:

```
IPhoneGameScene *nextScene = [IPhoneGameScene sceneWithPuzzle:[self.puzzle next]];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:nextScene];
```

So clean!

Comment: I'm not getting what IphoneGameScene and 'puzzle' is. It doesn't say anything about that on the link. I'm using cocos2d, remember

Comment: Sure, that was just an example of my code -- IPhoneGameScene is just a `CCLayer` subclass, and `puzzle` is an instance in my core data model. If you follow that blog post, my `puzzle` is the referenced `thing`.